# Nginx docker container doesn't accept request

Tags: nginx, docker

I am trying to run a Nginx web server on a docker container. What I have done:

```sh
$ docker pull nginx
$ docker run -d -p 8080:8080 --name nginx1 nginx
```

Then `docker ps` shows the container is running. Also tesing nginx is up:

```sh
$ docker exec -it nginx1 bash
root@...:/# service nginx status
[ ok ] nginx is running.
root@...:/# curl http://localhost:8080/

{Shows the content of html file located on /etc/nginx/html/index.html}

root@...:/# exit
exit
$ curl http://localhost:8080/

{Just loads and nothing happens} <- This is my problem
```

Netstat:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3776/docker-proxy   
tcp        0      1 172.17.0.1:36684        172.17.0.2:8080         SYN_SENT    3776/docker-proxy   
tcp       79      0 127.0.0.1:8080          127.0.0.1:41674         CLOSE_WAIT  3776/docker-proxy   
tcp        0      1 172.17.0.1:36682        172.17.0.2:8080         SYN_SENT    3776/docker-proxy   
tcp      555      0 127.0.0.1:8080          127.0.0.1:41672         ESTABLISHED 3776/docker-proxy   
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      3783/docker-proxy
```

I'm on fedora 34. Also running Nginx on my system (Not docker) on the same port works ok.

My `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 4096;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 8080;
    }

}
```

The last one in the bottom is the relevant server.

Comment: You can't run nginx on the host and port forward the same port into docker.

Comment: any relevant output from "docker logs nginx1" ?

Comment: @Own3r Nothing special. 4 times `root@...:/#`.

Comment: do you get the same behavior with curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/ ?

Comment: Maybe the routed to the docker-network are only present for "root"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firewall was the problem. On fedora:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=dmz --add-port=8080/tcp
```

On others it may be:

```
sudo ufw allow 8080
```

Answer (score 1):

The nginx image is exposing the port 80, not 8080.

```
docker run -d -p 8080:80 --name nginx1 nginx
```

Comment: This isn't working either. I also have a simple server config listening to port 8080. You can see `curl http://localhost:8080/` works on the container bash but not on my system.

Comment: Then please provide all relevant parts of your configuration. Your question shows nothing but an unmodified nginx container.